# BeanPostProcessor not called for @Bean methods with Spring Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I am trying to add a BeanPostProcessor in my Spring Java Config. It seems to be working *but only* for beans that are created through component scanning (@Configuration, @RestController, ..)

Beans that I create in my Java config are not.

E.g.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration
{
  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean()
  {
    return new MyBean();
  }


  @Bean
  public static MyBPP myBeanPostProcessor()
  {
    return new MyBPP();
  }
}
```

Notice I did declare the method of the BeanPostProcessor as static (See http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/123899-beanpostprocessor-with-bean-annotation-not-working).

So an instance of MyBean gets created but the BeanPostProcessor never processes it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try my test, it worked for me

```
class MyBPP implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        System.out.println(bean);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBPP myBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new MyBPP();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfiguration.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you add your println in the `postProcessAfterInitialization` ?

Comment: It did not work for me because the BeanPostProcessor had a bean autowired that was the target of the post processor as well. According to the docs, this cannot work. I had to break the kind of circular dependency I had to make it work.

Comment: With 'the docs', I mean http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension more specifically the note called "BeanPostProcessors and AOP auto-proxying"

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Man, I had the same issue, I thought I can use if `bean.equals(referencedAutowiredBean)` and BeanPostProcessor won't work, once I removed the referencedAutowiredBean and used if `beanName.equals(nameOfTheBean)` it started to WORK!

Comment: I have also spotted `INFO BeanPostProcessorChecker Bean is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors`